# How to generate one cartesian product in lisp?

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp, generator, cartesian-product

This is my code to generate a cartesian product:

```
(defun cartesian-product (LIST)
  (LOOP FOR X IN LIST
    NCONC
        (LOOP FOR Y IN LIST
         COLLECT (LIST X Y))))
```

I tried outputting one of the cartesian products with this:

```
(defun cartesian-product-generator (CALLBACK LIST)
  (LOOP FOR X IN LIST
    NCONC
        (LOOP FOR Y IN LIST
        DO(FUNCALL CALLBACK (LIST X Y)))))
```

However there are errors when I tried testing it with:

```
(cartesian-product-generator '(A B C))

Error: Too few arguments in call to #<Compiled-function cartesian-product-generator #x30200097E60F>:
       1 argument provided, at least 2 required.  While executing: cartesian-product-generator, in process listener(1).
```

I am new to LISP and would like to know why there's an error and how to fix this error. Ultimately, I would like to output each cartesian product per call of the function.

For example, if the lists consists of `((1 1) (1 2) (2 1) (2 2))`.
I would like to generate `(1 1)`. Then `(1 2)`. Then `(2 1)`. Lastly, `(2 2)`.

Comment: You have defined a function with two parameters: callback and list. You are calling the function with one argument: '(a b c). Isn't that obviously wrong?

Comment: `(loop for ... do ...)` does not return anything useful, it only calls the callback. So it is probably wrong to use its result in `(nconc ...)`. You must arrange your recursive calls so that you never use the return value, you only pass down data that is eventually given to callback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first code does work correctly.

```
(defun cartesian-product (list)
  (loop
    for x in list
    nconc (loop for y in list
                collect (list x y))))
```

Calling it with `'(a b c)` returns a list:

```
((A A) (A B) (A C) (B A) (B B) (B C) (C A) (C B) (C C))
```

You want to avoid building a list and use a callback instead.
To simplify, first try to only print elements instead of collecting them.

That means that *you do not care* about returning the generated values
up to the caller: you just want to generate them and print them as
soon as they are available.

Basically, you can replace all `nconc` and `collect` keywords by `do`, and add a call to `print`:

```
(defun cartesian-product (list)
  (loop
    for x in list
    do (loop for y in list
             do (print (list x y)))))
```

A quick test on the REPL with `'(a b c)` should print the same
elements as previously, each one on a separte line.

Now, you can just generalize `print` and call anything you want:

```
(defun map-cartesian-product (function list)
  (loop
    for x in list
    do (loop for y in list
             do (funcall function (list x y)))))
```

Just to see if it still works, do a quick test:

```
(map-cartesian-product #'print '(a b c))
```

This should have the same behaviour as before.

Since you only iterate over a list for side-effects, you can use
[`DOLIST`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_dolist.htm):

```
(defun map-cartesian-product (function list)
  (dolist (x list)
    (dolist (y list)
      (funcall function (list x y)))))
```

Again, you can test that it still works as previously.

Comment: What does funcall do? Why do you need to add funcall?

Comment: For (defun cartesian-product (list)
  (loop
    for x in list
    do (loop for y in list
             do (print (list x y)))))

Is it possible to do this without it printing?

Comment: `funcall` is used to call a function object; here `function` is a variable, if you wanted to do `(function (list x y))` instead, that would fail for two reasons: (1) function is a special operator in CL and (2) even if you used another name, you would search for that name in the function namespace, not the variable namespace (and here, you are manipulating the callback through the *variable* named `function`).

Comment: On [emacs.se](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/52490/2370) is now a generalization of your idea to arbitrary many sets.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into the `cl-coroutine` library available via `quicklisp`.  Then your `cartesian-product` could be written as

```
(cl-coroutine:defcoroutine cartesian-product (list)
  (loop for x in list
    do (loop for y in list
      do (cl-coroutine:yield (list x y)))))
```

An example use could be:

```
(cl-coroutine:with-coroutine (cartesian-product)
  (let ((x (list 1 2 3)))
    (loop for y = (cartesian-product x)
      while y do (print y))))

; outputs (1 1) (1 2) ... (3 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to leave my 2 cents here.

You can also do this with a macro

```lisp
(defmacro cartesian-product (lists)
  (let* ((indices (loop for i from 1 to (length lists)
                        collect (gensym (format nil "~a-i-" i))))
         (initial-value `(loop for ,(car (last indices)) in ',(car (last lists))
                               collect `(,,@indices))))
    (reduce
     (lambda (x y)
       `(loop for ,(car x) in ',(cadr x)
              nconc ,y))
     (mapcar #'list (butlast indices) (butlast lists))
     :from-end t
     :initial-value initial-value)))
```

which expands with

```lisp
(cartesian-product ((H P) (a b c) (1 2 3 5)))
```

to

```lisp
(loop for #:|1-i-806| in '(h p)
      nconc (loop for #:|2-i-807| in '(a b c)
                  nconc (loop for #:|3-i-808| in '(1 2 3 5)
                              collect `(,#:|1-i-806| ,#:|2-i-807| ,#:|3-i-808|))))
```

and results into

```lisp
((H A 1) (H A 2) (H A 3) (H A 5) (H B 1) (H B 2) (H B 3) (H B 5) (H C 1) (H C 2) (H C 3) (H C 5)
 (P A 1) (P A 2) (P A 3) (P A 5) (P B 1) (P B 2) (P B 3) (P B 5) (P C 1) (P C 2) (P C 3) (P C 5))
```

I like it because it is quite simple and does not require recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a more basic answer (without loops), but more general, i.e., cartesian products of two, three and four lists (your case is binary cartesian product with two identical arguments):

```
(defun make-tuples-with-object (obj lst)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (list obj x)) lst))
                
(defun cartesian-product (list-1 list-2)
  (apply #'append (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (make-tuples-with-object x list-2)) list-1)))

(defun cartesian-product-ternary (list-1 list-2 list-3)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (cons (car x) (second x)))
      (cartesian-product list-1 (cartesian-product list-2 list-3))))

(defun cartesian-product-quaternary (list-1 list-2 list-3 list-4)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (cons (car x) (second x)))
      (cartesian-product list-1 (cartesian-product-ternary list-2 list-3 list-4))))
```